# How to call J (ijconsole) with a script automatically

Tags: j

I'm using the J programming language in Ubuntu, and I'd like to call a script automatically from the command line. I think this should be possible using the ijconsole command, but I don't know how to pass it a set of functions.

For instance, in perl, one would type:

perl -e 'print "Hello";'

Is there an equivalent method for J, using the ijconsole program? For instance:

ijconsole -e 'load "script.ijs"'

Thank you!

Comment: So far, I've been able to figure out the following command:

echo "load 'script.ijs'" | ijconsole

Is there a more elegant way to do this? This seems a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `ijconsole` is in your path, you can run a script from the terminal command line as follows:

```
ijconsole script.ijs
```

If you want to run some commands (not in a script) then this will work:

```
ijconsole -js "echo 'Hello world'" "exit 0"
69
```

The command line options are documented [in the J user manual](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/cmdline.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Shell script invocations of J scripts are documented in the [J Shell Script](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/J_Shell_Script) page.

In a nutshell, all shell scripts can be directed to be run through an *interpreter* other than the default system shell (typically `sh`, `bash`, or `zsh`).  This is done with the first line having a "shebang":

```
#!/path/to/interpreter arguments...
... remainder of script
```

For example, ruby scripts can be invoked with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# ruby script ...
```

And, a J script can be invoked with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jconsole
NB. process ARGV and do something
args=.2{ARGV
exit 0
```

Here is a complete example of a J script:

```
$ cat tst.js
#!/Applications/j64/bin/jconsole
9!:7'+++++++++|-' NB. set ascii box mode
echo 'ARGV=';ARGV NB. show ARGV contents
args=.2}.ARGV     NB. de-head and return only the actual arguments
echo 'args=';args NB. show the actual args
exit''
```

and it's output when run:

```
$ ./tst.js foo bar bif
+-----+------------------------------+--------+---+---+---+
|ARGV=|/Applications/j64/bin/jconsole|./tst.js|foo|bar|bif|
+-----+------------------------------+--------+---+---+---+
+-----+---+---+---+
|args=|foo|bar|bif|
+-----+---+---+---+
```