# Run J script as if it were line-by-line entered into the interpreter

Tags: vim, j

Is there a way to run the script as if it were typed into the interpeter? The benefits are that I don't need echos everywhere, the work done is saved as a file, and I can use vim to do the editing. Example:

example.ijs

```
x =. 1
x + 3
```

terminal

```
   x =. 1
   x + 3
4
```

If not, I'll write a vimscript that can do the above then share them here. The advantage of a vimscript solution is that I could have commands to run the entire file, the current line, the current selection, everything up to and including the current line, or whatever else is useful.

Related but not a duplicate: [How to call J (ijconsole) with a script automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897187/how-to-call-j-ijconsole-with-a-script-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loadd` rather than `load` to run the script and display the lines and results.

```
   loadd 'example.ijs'
   x =. 1
   x + 3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking for this to be solved for the jconsole interface. I don't have answer for that, but would point out that that functionality is available for both the JHS and jQt interfaces. If you don't mind switching to a different interface then that would be a quick and easy solution.

Comment: I've tried jQt, but using it feels like I'm walking in molasses. Perhaps the best metaphor is writing code in Java (verbose) versus J (terse). Is there a way to pipe jQt through vim?

Comment: As for JHS, I'm reading about, but the documentation isn't so straightforward. The root page doesn't even describe what it is. Going up a level to the Guides section, JHS is described as an HTTP Server. I don't know what that is. Only the bottom of the JHS help page gets into a description, but doesn't really explain why I'd want to use it in the first place (it says something about making web apps, but it also sounds like a general interface?). I'll put it on my to do list to play around with it at some point, but I wonder if it's as convenient as vim to use.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to pipe jQt to vim, but my experience is mainly with the JHS and jQt interfaces alone. Eelvex's  answer regarding labs may be the option that you are looking for. The new version of labs is based on sp which is essentially the same library  but focussing on running scripts as input.

Comment: JHS is essentially a way to run J through a web browser using Javascript as an interface to the J engine. The HTTP server is the foundation of a local page the provides the interface to J. I don't think it suits your needs at this point, but you may want to look at it in the future.

Comment: I finished the vimscripts that run pieces of the file and I'll post them after looking through Eelvex's response. What's nice about the vimscript solution is they're language agnostic as far as I can tell; so far they work with J and Python.

Comment: JHS sounds really cool, though I'm ignorant about why one would want to run J through a web browser. Is there some convenience aspect I'm unaware of?

Comment: The biggest advantage I have found is that since you are already in a web environment, it allows you to run video, scalable vector graphics, audio and other web conveniences without leaving the interface. Some of the video labs that I have put together would be examples of this. You can't access them through the console though, they are only available on JHS and jQt at this time.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how that'd be useful!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to interactively run a script is to use `labs` command:

```
 load'labs/lab'

 lab'myscript.ijt'    
 1 of 2 in myscript.ijt
 x =. 1

 NB. press Ctrl+'.' to advance.
 x + 3
4

 NB. Run the whole script.
 lab 1 _
 x =. 1
 x + 3
4
```

More info about labs [here](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Labs/Index)

If you want to non-interactively run a script as if typed in the console, you can just feed the script to j (in linux):

```
j < myscript.ijs
4
```

[Alternatively](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/04.htm), to

> see the lines on the screen just as though they had been typed from the keyboard

from a script, you can use `0!:1`:

```
 0!:1 < 'myscript.ijs'
 x =. 1
 x + 3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wrote a working vimscript and I'll share it in a moment. For the labs, it looks like I'd have to change the file extension, which is not the ideal. The `0!:1` approach is very nice, but my script is only being recognized if I put the script in the J directory (for me: `J901`). I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that J tends to exit to its home directory. Is that normal? J seems to switch to its installation directory when `jconsole.cmd is` run.

Comment: If you use the full path, `0!:1 < 'c:\mypath\myscript'` should work.

Comment: So, it's normal for J to switch directories like that? In my experience, absolute paths are more fragile than paths relative to the script.

Answer (score 1):

This is the vimscript solution I mentioned. It's as far as I can tell language agnostic as well.

```
" Global variable dictates whether new terminals are opened
" horizontally ('h') or vertically ('v').
let g:terminalsplit = 'h'

" Add execution strings for each language you use.
augroup terminalcommands
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype j      let g:cmdstr = 'jconsole.cmd'
    autocmd Filetype python let g:cmdstr = 'python'
augroup END

" Close all terminals
nnoremap <silent> <leader>p :call CloseTerminal()<cr>
" Run file
nnoremap <leader>h :call Run(g:cmdstr, 'script')<cr>
" Run as if file were entered line-by-line into the interpreter
" Mappings for: Line, selection, file up to line, entire file
nnoremap <leader>j yy:call Run(g:cmdstr, 'interpreter')<cr>
vnoremap <leader>j ygv<esc>:call Run(g:cmdstr, 'interpreter')<cr>
nnoremap <leader>k Vggy<c-O>:call Run(g:cmdstr, 'interpreter')<cr>
nnoremap <leader>l mzggVGy'z:call Run(g:cmdstr, 'interpreter')<cr>

function! Run(cmdstr, mode)
    let filepath = expand('%:p') " Copy filepath before switch to terminal
    call CloseTerminal()
    call OpenTerminal()
    echo g:clear . " & " . a:cmdstr
    call feedkeys(g:clear . " & " . a:cmdstr) " Begin run command
    call RunCode(filepath, a:mode)
    call feedkeys("\<c-w>p") " Switch back to file window
endfunction

function! CloseTerminal()
    if has('nvim')
        let terminals = split(execute('filter/term:/ls'), '\n')
    else
        let terminals = split(execute('filter/!/ls'), '\n')
    endif
    for i in range(len(terminals))
        silent! exe "bd! " . split(terminals[i], '  ')[0]
    endfor
endfunction

function! OpenTerminal()
    if g:terminalsplit == 'h'
        terminal
    elseif g:terminalsplit == 'v'
        vertical terminal
    else
        echo 'g:terminalsplit=' . &g:terminalsplit . '. Must be "h" or "v".'
    endif
endfunction

function! RunCode(filepath, mode)
    if a:mode == 'script'
        call feedkeys(" " . a:filepath . "\<cr>")
    elseif a:mode == 'interpreter'
        call feedkeys("\<cr>")
        call feedkeys("\<c-w>\"\"")
    else
        echo 'a:mode=' . a:mode . '. Must be "script" or "interpreter".'
    endif
endfunction

" Use to clear the terminal window before running the script
if has('unix')
    let g:clear = 'clear'
else
    let g:clear = 'cls'
endif
```

Comment: You should post that over on the J programming forum. I am sure there are people over there that would love to see what you have done. http://www.jsoftware.com/mailman/listinfo/programming

Comment: Perfect timing! I just subscribed last week. (: